# justification=justified not working in caption of figure

Tags: captions

Ragged right is working but when justified used, it's centering the caption.

```
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,
   justification=justified,
   format=plain]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

[image]`

Comment: justified captions are the default in most classes even without using those caption package declarations. So your layout is due to code you have not shown. Please always post a complete small example that shows the problem. We can not debug code we can not see.

Comment: Several document classes are not compatible with the caption package (often deliberately).